# How to override the Custom Button on the related list on the Case object?

Tags: custom-button

I am looking to create a New Custom Button which I have created and wanted to used on the page layout of the related list shown in the below screen shot. How we can used that ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to edit this via the Page Layout for the Object.

To edit a related list, double-click it. If you’re using the enhanced page layout editor, you can also click the wrench icon

Click + in the Buttons section to customize which standard and custom buttons are displayed in the related list.

The custom button must be defined for the object contained in the related list, not the parent object, and the button Type must be List Button. For example, to display a custom button on the Contacts related list of an account, define the custom button for contacts, not accounts.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you please add screen shot to support your answer please?

Comment: I am not able to get this above window. How we can go there ?

Comment: quoting from my answer: "The custom button must be defined for the object contained in the related list, not the parent object, and the button Type must be List Button. "

Comment: ok got it. Thnx